# Optional first match regex can be identical to second match

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to get 3 matches from each line of a string:

```
m&tch1@ match2@  match3canbe&ny7hing
match2@          match3canbe&ny7hing
```

- Match 1 can be anything non-whitespace, it doesn't always end with @
- If Match 1 exists, it is separated from Match 2 with a space (the space is not part of the match)
- Match 2 is always a normal word and always ends in @
- Match 3 is anything

So from the above, I want:

```
Match 1
1.  m&tch1@
2.  match2
3.  match3canbe&ny7hing
Match 2
1.  
2.  match2
3.  match3canbe&ny7hing
```

I came up with this: `/^(\S*@?) ?(\w+)@ +(.+)/` but it returns:

```
Match 1
1.  m&tch1@
2.  match2
3.  match3canbe&ny7hing
Match 2
1.  match
2.  2
3.  match3canbe&ny7hing
```

Match 1 is fine, but for Match 2 the first group should be empty and the second group should be 'match2'

If it can't be done with regex alone, any other suggestions?

**UPD:** sawa's solution works but if I prefix the lines with anything e.g. a tab:

```
prefix m&tch1: match2: match3canbe&ny7hing
prefix match2: match3canbe&ny7hing
```

and scan it like so: `/^prefix (\S*)\s+(\S*):\s+(\S+)/`
it only scans one line

Current: http://rubular.com/r/expKw59fF2
With prefixes(not working yet): http://rubular.com/r/VWGgU1qNWA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.scan(/(\S*)\s+(\S*)@\s+(\S+)/)
```

returns:

```
[
  [
    "m&tch1@",
    "match2",
    "match3canbe&ny7hing"
  ],
  [
    "",
    "match2",
    "match3canbe&ny7hing"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Ok, now I've run into another problem, what if the lines start with a character that I want to filter out? E.g. if every line is indented with a tab, it doesn't seem to scan more than one line if I prefix it with '^\t'

Comment: `^` means "beginning of the string". If you want it to mean "beginning of each line" you need to turn the "m" option on.

Comment: Current:  http://rubular.com/r/expKw59fF2    With prefixes: http://rubular.com/r/VWGgU1qNWA Now it only comes up with one match =[

Comment: Ok, I gave up and used a different way, thx for help anyway :)